# Using Roslyn to find interfaces within a solution

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

The intent of the below code is to find all interfaces within a solution whose fully-qualified names match the given predicate. It seems to work, but as I am new to Roslyn I'm guessing there are things that could be improved. I'd appreciate any pointers.

```
public async Task<IImmutableList<INamedTypeSymbol>> GetMatchingInterfacesInSolution(string solutionPath, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.Select(x => x.GetCompilationAsync()));

    return compilations
        .SelectMany(x => x.SyntaxTrees.Select(y => new { Compilation = x, SyntaxTree = y }))
        .Select(x => x.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(x.SyntaxTree))
        .SelectMany(
            x => x
                .SyntaxTree
                .GetRoot()
                .DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>()
                .Select(y => x.GetDeclaredSymbol(y)))
        .Where(x => predicate(x.ToDisplayString()))
        .ToImmutableList();
}
```

Here's another approach I tried. I couldn't really see any benefit to doing it this way. It's more verbose and difficult to follow:

```
public static async Task<IImmutableList<INamedTypeSymbol>> GetMatchingInterfacesInSolution(string solutionPath, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.Select(x => x.GetCompilationAsync()));

    return compilations
        .Select(x => x.Assembly.GlobalNamespace)
        .SelectMany(x => FindInterfacesRecursive(x, predicate))
        .ToImmutableList();
}

private static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> FindInterfacesRecursive(INamespaceSymbol @namespace, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var member in @namespace.GetMembers())
    {
        var childNamespace = member as INamespaceSymbol;

        if (childNamespace != null)
        {
            foreach (var @interface in FindInterfacesRecursive(childNamespace, predicate))
            {
                yield return @interface;
            }

            continue;
        }

        var namedType = member as INamedTypeSymbol;

        if (namedType == null || namedType.TypeKind != TypeKind.Interface)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (predicate == null || predicate(namedType.ToDisplayString()))
        {
            yield return namedType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Roslyn are you using? This doesn't compile for me under 1.0.0-rc1 unless I change the return type to `Task<IImmutableList<ISymbol>>`.

Comment: @mjolka: I am using 1.0.0-rc1. Not sure why it's not compiling for you - this is my exact code and it compiles fine. I am compiling for FX4.5 - you?

Comment: Very strange. Yes, targeting .NET 4.5 -- I've put the code up [here](https://github.com/mjolka/RoslynTest).

Comment: I haven't used this myself, but I have a feeling that that the [SymbolFinder](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder.cs,fd299f73032d2f26) class, and especially the [SymbolFinder.FindImplementationsAsync](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_Hierarchy.cs,6de07857600d87fb) static method will be of some help to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Name captured variables as you would name local variables.
- First `SelectMany` and `Select` can be merged into a single `SelectMany`.

code:

```
public async Task<IImmutableList<ISymbol>> GetMatchingInterfacesInSolution(string solutionPath, Func<string, bool> predicate)
{
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    var compilations = await Task.WhenAll(solution.Projects.Select(x => x.GetCompilationAsync()));

    return compilations
        .SelectMany(compilation => compilation.SyntaxTrees.Select(syntaxTree => compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree)))
        .SelectMany(
            semanticModel => semanticModel
                .SyntaxTree
                .GetRoot()
                .DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>()
                .Select(interfaceDeclarationSyntax => semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(interfaceDeclarationSyntax)))
        .Where(symbol => predicate(symbol.ToDisplayString()))
        .ToImmutableList();
}
```

Comment: Good points, both. I really do need to get out the habit of lazily naming my lambda parameters...

Answer (score 1):

```
return compilations
    .SelectMany(x => x.SyntaxTrees.Select(y => new { Compilation = x, SyntaxTree = y }))
    .Select(x => x.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(x.SyntaxTree))
    .SelectMany(
        x => x
            .SyntaxTree
            .GetRoot()
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>()
            .Select(y => x.GetDeclaredSymbol(y)))
    .Where(x => predicate(x.ToDisplayString()))
    .ToImmutableList();
```

This is the kind of code that would benefit from using LINQ query syntax:

```
return (from compilation in compilations
        from syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees
        select compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree) into semanticModel
        from interfaceDeclaration in semanticModel
            .SyntaxTree
            .GetRoot()
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>()
        select semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(interfaceDeclaration) into symbol
        where predicate(symbol.ToDisplayString())
        select symbol)
    .ToImmutableList();
```

Comment: Why does this benefit from the query syntax? Does this make it faster or is it just easier for you to parse? 
As far as I know (don't usually use it) the IL code will call all the same methods....

Comment: @user3797758 You're right, it's not faster, but I find it easier to read.